# How to parse this JSON into java object?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

http://pastebin.com/rXbeKqAa

Hi all I have been trying to parse the above JSON into a java program and store it into an object... (Don't have a specific structure at the moment, as long as I can get the data from the object.)

Have been trying to use GSON but I can't seem to get it right..

```
        String inputLine="";
    HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://localhost:3000/specs/215/errors.js");
    HttpResponse response =httpclient.execute(method);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

    inputLine = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray array = parser.parse(inputLine).getAsJsonArray();

    for(int i=0; i < array.size(); i++) {

        Errors e = gson.fromJson(array.get(0), Errors.class);
        System.out.println(e.error.getReason());
    }
```

and the error i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:99)
    at test.Getter.main(Getter.java:37)
```

Anyone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: (Assuming the JSON is actually all on one line.) It's not an array, it's an object containing an "errors" array, and a "warnings" array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON String is not a JSON Array String. JSON String starts and ends with `{`, `}` respectively while JSON Array starts and ends with `[`, `]` respectively.

This line is wrong:

```
JsonArray array = parser.parse(inputLine).getAsJsonArray();
```

Rather retrieve it as a `JsonObject`.

Comment: Great - thanks!

By first getting it as a jsonobject and then paring it as array works.

JsonObject jso = parser.parse(inputLine).getAsJsonObject();
     JsonArray array = parser.parse(jso.get("warnings").toString()).getAsJsonArray();

Answer (score 0):

JSON Structures are realized as an object, record,struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.

You can use eval() function to achieve the desired goal.
I think this will help you/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue I had. Novice mistake with the serialized annotations. For some reason I thought they would reference the name of the class not the field names. But more importantly, I also had to create a root-level container class to hold my classes. That allowed for all the objects to be parsed.